# Python3.7 CSV file with multiples tables, how to get the middle table only

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file with multiples headers and tables which was created by our system. Number of rows are dynamics but the table title name is always the same. Between each table, there's a blank row.
I'm using python3.7.3 and want to get the middle table(Device table) then upload to our database.

How can I do to get the middle table only? Can regex work with CSV file in this case?

Original file:

```
Report title:ABC
Created Date:Jul-15-2019

Model
Model Name,Number
abc,1
abc,2

Device
Device Name,Number
efg,1
efg,2
efg,3

Missing Device
Device Name,Number
xyz,3
xyz,4
```

The table I want to have(without table name):

```
Device Name,Number
efg,1
efg,2
efg,3
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! If you already haven't, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried until this point ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know, that all tables are separated by a newline you could just count the newlines and then parse the target table. Something like that:

```
import csv

table_ix = 2
with open('test.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    empty_line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if len(row) == 0:
            empty_line_count += 1
        if empty_line_count == table_ix:
            # do your parsing here
            print(row)
```

Its not beautiful but it works. But I would suggest that you look at tools like Pandas etc.

Comment: It's a good idea but won't be suitable for this file as sometimes it contains an additional table or reduces a table, it's not always at the second table...

Comment: You can change the index dynamically during runtime if you wanted to. Or write a method that accepts the index as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach:

1. Open the file for input
2. Skip all the lines until you reach the one that contains the header
3. From there, take all the lines that are not empty
4. Feed these lines into a CSV reader

#### Code

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('report.txt') as fh:
    fh = itertools.dropwhile(lambda line: 'Device Name,Number' not in line, fh)
    fh = itertools.takewhile(lambda line: line != '\n', fh)
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

#### Output

```
['Device Name', 'Number']
['efg', '1']
['efg', '2']
['efg', '3']
```

#### Notes

- I used `itertools.dropwhile` to perform step #2
- ... and `itertools.takewhile` for step #3